# Unknown parameter: POST, GET in .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache

I am new to Apache/PHP, and I want to initiate a new project by copying it from one laptop to mine. I have installed Apache, etc. Now, when I try to access "Myproject/" in the browser, I encounter an error that is logged in the `apache_error.log` file.

> C:/wamp64/www/Myproject/.htaccess: Unknown parameter: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, referer: http://localhost/

`.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    Header add set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    Header add set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"


    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I'm not an Apache expert, but `add set` seems wrong. You can `always set` or `onsuccess set`, but I don't think that's a valid option.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.